# Intuitive meaning of the exponential form of an unitary operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory

I'm an undergraduate student in Chemistry currently studying quantum mechanics and I have a problem with unitary transformations. 
Here in my book, it is stated that

> Every unitary operator $\hat{\mathcal{U}}$ can be written in an exponential form as follows:
>   $$\mathrm{e}^{-i\alpha\hat{\mathcal{T}}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k!}\left(-i\alpha\right)^{k}\hat{\mathcal{T}}^{k}
>  $$

Provided that I have no knowledge of Lie Group/Algebra, my questions are:

- Why a unitary operator can be always represented by an exponential form?
- What is the intuitive mathematical meaning of the exponential form/matrix?
- What is the relation between the operator $\hat{\mathcal{U}}$ and the operator $\hat{\mathcal{T}}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are we to assume that $\hat{\mathcal{T}}$ is a self-adjoint operator?  Or, is there some other similar restriction on $\hat{\mathcal{T}}$?  For general operators, it can't be guaranteed that $\exp(-ia\hat{\mathcal{T}})$ is unitary.

Comment: Cross posted: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133758/intuitive-meaning-of-the-exponential-form-of-an-unitary-operator-in-quantum-mech

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I think that's the reverse of the question being asked, since it's asking for why $\hat{\mathcal{T}}$ exists given a unitary $\hat{\mathcal{U}}$.

Comment: @Semiclassical fair point.

Comment: Sorry for not having specified earlier. We assume that $\hat{\mathcal{F}}$ is a self-adjoint operator since it represents some observable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spectral theorem for normal operators on a Hilbert space gives you the result, but you don't get a unique selfadjoint $T$. Any unitary $U$ can be written as
$$
                            U = \int_{|\lambda|=1}\lambda dE(\lambda),
$$
where $E$ is the unique spectral measure associated with $U$. Choose a branch of $\log$ and define
$$
                         T = -i\int_{|\lambda|=1}\log(\lambda)dE(\lambda).
$$
Then $\log(\lambda)$ is purely imaginary and $T=T^{\star}$. By the functional calculus,
$$
      e^{iT} = \exp\left\{\int_{|\lambda|=1}\log(\lambda)dE(\lambda)\right\}
             = \int_{|\lambda|=1}e^{\log(\lambda)}dE(\lambda) = U.
$$
This $T$ is rarely useful to you as an observable because $T$ is a bounded linear operator with $\|T\| \le 2\pi$. Exponentiation does this. If $H$ is a selfadjoint linear operator (possibly unbounded),
$$
                           H = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lambda dF(\lambda)
$$
and
$$
                e^{iH} = \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{i\lambda}dF(\lambda),
$$
but there's no general way to find $H$ from $e^{iH}$. If you know $e^{itH}$ for $t$ in a range of values $[0,\epsilon]$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, then you can recover $H$ using differentiation in $t$, but not just from knowing $e^{iH}$.

Comment: Can the ambiguity in the matrix logarithm be characterized more sharply? For instance, what can be said about $H'-H$ if $e^{i H'}=e^{i H}$?

Comment: @Semiclassical If $\{ e_{n} \}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal basis of $X$, then $Hx=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}2\pi n(x,e_{n})e_{n}$ satisfies $e^{iH}=e^{i0}=I$. If $H=\int t dE(t)$, $H'=\int tdE'(t)$ are unbounded or bounded selfadjoint operators with spectral measures $E$, $E'$, then $e^{iH}=e^{iH'}$ if $F(S)=E(\cup_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(S+2\pi n))=E'(\cup_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(S+2\pi n))$ for any subset $S\subseteq [0,2\pi)$. In that case $K=\int_{[0,2\pi)}tdF(t)$ satisfies $e^{iK}=e^{iH}=e^{iH'}$ and $K$ is unique among selfadjoint operators with $\sigma(K)\subseteq [0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @Semiclassical The uniqueness of $K$ that I gave above also requires that $2\pi$ is not in the point spectrum.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Thanks!

Comment: @DavideLaVardera : You are welcome.